# Creating a local SQL database for testing

Tags: sql

I am creating a VB.net application that will connect to a Microsoft SQL database. I first just want to test the application locally. What is the best/easiest way to set up the database? Do I need to create a SQL server or can I just store the database as a file? I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're targeting SQL Server 2005 or 2008, your best solution would be to install SQL Server Express.

[SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx)

[SQL Server 2005 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21844)

Comment: Once I have it installed, how would I connect to it from Visual Studio?

Comment: @Johan: Are you asking how to connect to it from the development environment, or from within your application? In both cases, the procedure would be the same as it would be if you were connecting to a remote server.

Comment: I was referring to the developing environment. I will try again to connect to it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use an SQL Express instance on your local machine.

Look at: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx to get started.